# Blocking Updating or Inserting an Entity when using Cascade in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity , EntHesaplasma , this entity has a relationship with EntCariHareketler entity. I have a foreign key in the EntHesaplasma entity for EntCariHareketler. I want to set a relationship between them , but I dont want to update,insert or remove operations on EntCariHareketler entity. Only I want to read operation on the second entity (EntCariHareketler). I tried Cascading types , but i could not get a success.

Below you can see partial of my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XOZ_HESAPLASMA")
public class EntHesaplasma {

    Integer hesaplasmaid;
    EntCariHareketler carihareket;
    String hesaplasmagrup;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "hesaplasmaid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getHesaplasmaid() {
        return hesaplasmaid;
    }

    public void setHesaplasmaid(Integer hesaplasmaid) {
        this.hesaplasmaid = hesaplasmaid;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="carihareketid")
    public EntCariHareketler getCarihareket() {
        return carihareket;
    }

public void setCarihareket(EntCariHareketler carihareket) {
    this.carihareket = carihareket;
}

@Column(name="hesaplasmagrup")
public String getHesaplasmagrup() {
    return hesaplasmagrup;
}

public void setHesaplasmagrup(String hesaplasmagrup) {
    this.hesaplasmagrup = hesaplasmagrup;
}
```

And this is EntCarihareketler entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI")
public class EntCariHareketler {

    private Integer cha_RECno;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "cha_recno", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getCha_RECno() {
        return cha_RECno;
    }

    public void setCha_RECno(Integer cha_RECno) {
        this.cha_RECno = cha_RECno;
    }
```

When I want to save the enthesaplasma object, i do not want to update or insert entCariHareketler entity, i got an exception like that the entcarihareketler entity could not insert. But i do not want to insert entcarihareketler entity. hibernate try to insert that entity, (btw in entcarihareket entity i do not use some fields which are part of primary keys. i only use cha_Recno as primary key. this is important field in the composite primary keys.)

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = null;

try {


         EntHesaplasma hesaplasma= new EntHesaplasma();
         hesaplasma.setHesaplasmagrup("a record");
         // related entcarihareketler entity
         EntCariHareketler entCariHareketler= new EntCariHareketler();
         // we set entcarihareketler id (1212) as primary key )
         entCariHareketler.setCha_RECno(1212);

tx=session.beginTransaction();
session.save(hesaplasma); 
tx.commit();

} catch (HibernateException e) {
if (tx != null)tx.rollback();
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
session.close();
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Instead of telling us what you don't want to do, could you explain us what you want to do, give an example, show what you've tried?

Comment: "but i could not get a success": what happened? Exception? Unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you never want to modify the `EntCariHareketler`, you could simply annotate it with [@Immutable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html).
2. If you the entity is mutable but you want to disable updates from the other side, you need to set to `false` the `insertable` and `updatable` `@JoinColumn` attribute:

   ```
   @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="carihareketid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   public EntCariHareketler getCarihareket() {
       return carihareket;
   }
   ```

Comment: i tried insertable=false and updatable=false, however it updates the second table, but @immutable works and blocks updating. thank you very much. :)

Comment: The `updatable = false` should not propagate the FK change, but is still allows changing `EntCariHareketler`. You need to annotate the `EntCariHareketler` as  @Immutable, if you don't ever want to change it.